# org.slf4j Gradle Dependency resolution

Tags: android, gradle, thrift

In my project I am trying to add thrift 0.9.1 dependency
compile (group: 'org.apache.thrift', name: 'libthrift', version: '0.9.1')

The project compiles fine but at runtime I am getting
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
I ran ./gradlew app:dependencies

```
_prodDebugCompile
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0 -> 24.1.0
|    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.4.0
|    |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:9.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:9.4.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:9.4.0
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-clearcut:9.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:9.4.0
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:9.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:9.4.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 (*)
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:9.4.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.4.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:9.4.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:24.1.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.1.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.1.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.0
+--- com.android.support:design:24.1.0
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.0 (*)
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.0
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.0 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v13:24.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.0 (*)
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0
|    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0
|    |    +--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    |    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-applinks:1.4.0
|    |         \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.4.0
|    +--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0 -> 24.1.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 24.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:customtabs:23.4.0
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0 -> 24.1.0
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0 -> 24.1.0 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2
|    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
+--- org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28
+--- com.darwinsys:hirondelle-date4j:1.5.1
+--- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1 -> 2.4
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.3.0
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.3.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0 (*)
+--- com.squareup:otto:1.3.8
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0
+--- com.leanplum:Leanplum:1.2.23
+--- com.apptentive:apptentive-android:3.0.1
+--- com.jumio.android:core:2.2.1
+--- com.jumio.android:nv:2.2.1
+--- com.jumio.android:nv-barcode:2.2.1
+--- com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.3
|    +--- com.stripe:stripe-java:1.40.0
|    |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4 -> 2.4
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4 -> 2.4
+--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14
+--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1
|    \--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.13 -> 1.0.14
+--- com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:6.3.1
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0 -> 9.4.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1 -> 24.1.0
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 -> 24.1.0 (*)
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.6
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.3.8
|    |    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.6 (*)
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10
|    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.10
|    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.1.4
+--- project :libraries:photoview-android:library
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1 -> 24.1.0 (*)
+--- project :libraries:fast-scroller:fastscroll
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1 -> 24.1.0 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1 -> 24.1.0 (*)
+--- org.apache.thrift:libthrift:0.9.1
|    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.5.8 -> 1.7.5
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1
|    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.5
|    |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4
|    |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|    |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
|    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4
+--- com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.1.1
|    +--- commons-cli:commons-cli:1.2
|    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
+--- com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.1.1
|    +--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0 -> 2.3.0 (*)
|    +--- com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.1.1 (*)
|    \--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
+--- com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1
|    \--- com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-analyzer:1.3.1
|         +--- com.squareup.haha:haha:1.3
|         \--- com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-watcher:1.3.1
**\--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5**
```

I am unable to decipher where the org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5 is coming from? No where in my gradle we add it. Also its present only for Debug.
 Thrifts dependency is resolving from 1.5.8 -> 1.7.5, though its still causing runtime error.

Any pointers to debug/fix this?

Comment: Do you have any `apply plugin` lines outside of the usual `com.android.application` plugin? Wondering if another plugin might be bringing that in. You might also check in your root `build.gradle` to make sure it's not applying a dependency.

Comment: I think the message you encounter is not preventing your program from running correctly. It's simply an error SLF4J writes to stderr to make you aware of possible configuration issues with your logging. As thrift requires SLF4J you won't be able to get rid of it. To eliminate the error message you need to provide a SLF4J compatible logger implementation on the class path, such as Log4J or slf4j-simple.

Comment: @kcoppock I do other pulgins applied:
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'net.saliman.cobertura' Strange it wont say which plugin its coming from

Comment: @dpr it does cause runtime crash unless I catch the exception. If the dependencies get resolved correctly. If I use latest thrift version it uses higher version of sl4j and no more run into this issue.

Comment: Once I put compile (group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-android', version:"1.7.12") my crash went away. Thus am not blocked.